# U with $\mathfrak{i}$ and $\mathfrak{r}$?

Tags: symbols

I want a `U`, with the symbols `$\mathfrak{i}$` and `$\mathfrak{r}$` stacked up on each other between the parallel vertical lines. They should not protrude higher than the height of the `U`. It is for a mathematical text, to denote a universe which is *regular* and *invariant*; so there are no conditions upon `U` besides that `$\mathfrak{i}$` and `$\mathfrak{r}$` should be legible.

Comment: Off topic, but this might be bad for accessibility. If I were you I would try with one of the present symbols in unicode-math.

Comment: @mickep: True, in general, but I don't think these symbols are defined, and am not sure you can actually stack  and  atop of one another, all within the confines of a capital U.

Comment: @Ingmar - "[I] am not sure you can actually stack  and  atop of one another". What about the suggestions provided in my answer? :-)

Comment: @Mico: I meant using Unicode only. Your solution works, and might in fact be the only way to achieve this. Not sure using \mathfrak{i} instead of  really would make a difference.

Comment: @Ingmar - Many thanks for providing this clarification. I suppose an advantage of using `\mathfrak` -- in conjunction with the machinery of the `mathalpha` package -- is that one can choose from quite a few Fraktur fonts, as long as they provide lowercase letters. In contrast, with `` and `` one is stuck with whatever the (presumably Opentype) math font offers "built in".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(edited to add a second possibility)

Here are two possible solutions; one uses `\mathbf{U}`, the other `\mathsf{U}`. I've tested them with Computer Modern math fonts and Euler fraktur fonts only, and exclusively in `\textstyle`. These symbols will never occur in first- or second-level subscripts, right?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frak=euler]{mathalpha}
\newcommand\Uira{\ooalign{$\mathbf{U}$\cr%
   \hfil\kern0.8pt\raise0.82ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\mathfrak{i}$}\hfil\cr%
   \hfil\kern0.8pt\raise0.18ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\mathfrak{r}$}\hfil\cr}}
\newcommand\Uirb{\ooalign{$\mathsf{U}$\cr%
   \hfil\raise0.82ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\mathfrak{i}$}\hfil\cr%
   \hfil\raise0.19ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\mathfrak{r}$}\hfil\cr}}

\begin{document}
The symbols $\Uira$ and $\Uirb$ denote...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Is there a way to do the same for \bigsqcap?

Comment: @Sapiens - The `\bigsqcap` macro is defined by quite a few math packages -- do you have a specific one in mind? If it's the `stmaryrd` package, you could take `\newcommand\bigsqcapir{\ooalign{$\bigsqcap$\cr \hfil\raise0.4ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathfrak{i}$}\hfil\cr \hfil\lower0.4ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathfrak{r}$}\hfil\cr}}` as a starting point. Note that I'd use `\scriptstyle` instead of `\scriptscriptstyle` as there's now a lot more vertical space to work with.

Comment: The stmaryrd looks ok.

Comment: I will try your suggestion now.

Comment: It's cool! Thank!

Answer (score 11):

I stack “i” over ”r” and scale the stack to have the same height as “U”.

The ”U” and the stack are superimposed to each other (the latter shifted a bit to the right in order to cope with the heavier left stroke).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Uir}{\mathpalette\Uir@\relax}

\newcommand{\Uir@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\mathrm{U}$}%
  \setbox\tw@=\vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      $\m@th#1\mathfrak{i}$\cr
      \noalign{\vskip0.5pt}
      $\m@th#1\mathfrak{r}$\cr
      \noalign{\vskip1.5pt}
     }%
  }%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\mathrm{U}$\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1\mkern1mu$\resizebox{!}{\ht\z@}{\box\tw@}\hidewidth\cr
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\Uir \quad \scriptstyle \Uir
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! What is the role of \scriptstyle?

Also, as I as well asked Mico: is there a way to do this for \bigsqcap?

Comment: The `` and `` glyphs look rather skinny. Is that because they're being scaled down from the basic (text-style) size of the glyphs? Applying the scaling to `\scriptscriptstyle\mathfrak{i}` and `\scriptscriptstyle\mathfrak{r}` might make the glyphs' strokes quite a bit thicker.

Comment: @Mico Not really, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Sapiens `\scriptstyle` is just used in the example in order to show that the symbol scales properly in subscripts.

Comment: Nevermind. I had been playing around with `\usepackage[frak=stixtwo]{mathalpha}` as the source for math-Fraktur letters, and I ended up improperly comparing your output (which uses the "Euler" math-Fraktur letters) with what's produced by employing the Stix2 Fraktur letters. Talk about comparing apples to oranges...