# $\mediumsqcap$ without $\mathfrak{I}$ and $\mathfrak{r}$

Tags: macros, symbols

The nice answers to my question [U with $\mathfrak{i}$ and $\mathfrak{r}$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682416/u-with-mathfraki-and-mathfrakr) gave me these

```
\newcommand\bigsqcapir{\ooalign{$\bigsqcap$\cr 
  \hfil\raise0.4ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathfrak{i}$}\hfil\cr     
  \hfil\lower0.4ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathfrak{r}$}\hfil\cr}}

\newcommand\bigsqcapi{\ooalign{$\bigsqcap$\cr 
  \hfil\raise0.4ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathfrak{i}$}\hfil\cr}}

\newcommand\bigsqcapr{\ooalign{$\bigsqcap$\cr  
  \hfil\lower0.4ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathfrak{r}$}\hfil\cr}}
```

How may I obtain an empty `\mediumsqcap` which has the same size as `$\bigscapr$`, `$\bigscapi$` and `$\bigscapir$`?

Comment: If you want the same size, that should be the unadorned `$\bigsqcap$`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton No, \(\bigsqcap\) is larger than \(\bigscapr\),  \(\bigscapi\) and (\bigscapir\).

Comment: If it's smaller, then it's almost certainly `\textstyle\bigsqcap` rather than `\displaystyle`.  There is no "medium size" per se.  In your definitions, it`s frozen between `$...$`, thus text style, and you're probably now trying to use the unembellished one in a display (`equation` or `align`, etc.).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. But  my understanding of these matters is so weak that I cannot even interpret  what you just stated.

Comment: "\mediumsqcap" was just a manner of writing, to indicate the size of (\bigscapr), (\bigscapi\) and (\bigscapir\), which is between \(\sqcap\) and \(\bigsqcap\).

Comment: There are two sizes of `\bigsqcap`, one for use inline within text, and the other for use in displayed equations,  Try using `\text{$\bigsqcap$}`; that is equivalent to the `\textstyle` that I mentioned before, but may be a bit easier to understand.  The `\text` must be used within a math environment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I do not observe differences in size, with $\text{$\bigsqcap$}$ and $\bigsqcap$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution given below defines a macro called `\tsbigsqcap`, where "ts" is mnemonic for "text style". The size of the symbol it produces is the same regardless of whether it occurs in inline math mode (which uses `\textstyle` by default) and displayed math mode (which uses `\displaystyle` by default).

[image]

To make size comparisons easy, the final line in the preceding screenshot groups the symbols `\sqcap`, `\tsbigsqcap`, and `\bigsqcap` in displaystyle math mode.

As is the case for the macros `\bigsqcapir`, `\bigsqcapi`, and `\bigsqcapr`, the macro `\tsbigsqcap` should not be used in first- or second-level subscripts and superscripts. I trust this constraint isn't binding in practice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % a font package that provides a '\bigsqcap' macro 
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for '\mathfrak' macro

\newcommand\bigsqcapir{\ooalign{$\bigsqcap$\cr 
  \hfil\raise0.4ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathfrak{i}$}\hfil\cr 
  \hfil\lower0.5ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathfrak{r}$}\hfil\cr}}
\newcommand\bigsqcapi{\ooalign{$\bigsqcap$\cr 
  \hfil\raise0.4ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathfrak{i}$}\hfil\cr}}   
\newcommand\bigsqcapr{\ooalign{$\bigsqcap$\cr  
  \hfil\lower0.5ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathfrak{r}$}\hfil\cr}}

% 'ts' in '\tsbigsqcap' is mnemonic for "text style"
\newcommand\tsbigsqcap{{\textstyle\bigsqcap}}

\begin{document}

\centering

% inline math mode uses "\textstyle" by default:
$uuu \bigsqcapir \bigsqcapi \bigsqcapr \tsbigsqcap vvv$

\[ % now display math 
uuu \bigsqcapir \bigsqcapi \bigsqcapr \tsbigsqcap vvv
\]

\verb+\sqcap+ \verb+\tsbigsqcap+ \verb+\bigsqcap+ in display-math mode
\[
- \sqcap \tsbigsqcap \bigsqcap -
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might add an "unadjusted" `\bigsqcap` and some visible explanatory text to the example to make this more immediately obvious.  Also `\[...\]` might be helpful for future visitors.  Subtlety isn't necessarily a virtue in explanations like this one.

Comment: @Mico Thanks! Strangely, the empty cap appeared wider to me, but I now believe it is a visual illusion: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dafw3p3qpj6lqut/Screen%20Shot%202023-04-19%20at%2012.10.38.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @Sapiens - Definitely a visual illusion.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks for your suggestion, which I've gladly implemented.