# $\Omega$ filled with +?

Tags: symbols

Compare my question [U with $\mathfrak{i}$ and $\mathfrak{r}$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682416/u-with-mathfraki-and-mathfrakr).

How may one fill `$\Omega$` so that it has a plus sign in the middle?

Comment: I don't understand.  Take an answer to your other question, change U to \Omega and the mathfrak to +, and adjust the spacing.  What are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Teepeeemm These things are difficult, as are the things I focus upon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does one of the following possibilities strike your fancy?

[image]

If you want to raise the `+` less far than is done in the screenshot, just choose a smaller value in the first argument of `\raisebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\Omegaplusa{\ooalign{$\Omega$\cr%
   \hfil\raisebox{0.60ex}{$\scriptstyle+$}\hfil}}
\newcommand\Omegaplusb{\ooalign{$\Omega$\cr%
   \hfil\raisebox{0.85ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle+$}\hfil}}

\begin{document}
The symbols $\Omegaplusa$ and $\Omegaplusb$ denote \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remark: As with my answers to some of the OP's previous symbol-related queries, this answer also assumes that this symbol will never occur in first-level, let alone second-level subscripts or superscripts.

Answer (score 9):

With size changing in subscripts or superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\Omegaplus}{}{{\mathpalette\Omegaplus@\relax}}
\newcommand{\Omegaplus@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\Omega$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th#1\nonscript\mkern0.05mu\mkern0.1mu$}
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\z@-\height+\wd\tw@}{\scalebox{0.7}{$\m@th#1+$}}%
    \hidewidth\cr
    $\m@th#1\Omega$\cr
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\Omegaplus_{\Omegaplus_{\Omegaplus}}$

\Large$\Omegaplus_{\Omegaplus_{\Omegaplus}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or maybe

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\Omegaplus}{}{{\mathpalette\Omegaplus@\relax}}
\newcommand{\Omegaplus@}[2]{%
  \vphantom{\Omega}%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\Omega$}%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth
    \raisebox{0.9\dimexpr\ht\z@-\height}{\scalebox{0.5}{$\m@th#1\bm{+}$}}%
    \hidewidth\cr
    $\m@th#1\Omega$\cr
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\Omegaplus_{\Omegaplus_{\Omegaplus}}$

\Large$\Omegaplus_{\Omegaplus_{\Omegaplus}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the last one, but unfortunately, with me, the upper plus-lines touch Omega.

Comment: @Sapiens What math fonts are you using?

Comment: I do not know. How may I find out?

Comment: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters?

Comment: I tried to surround with \mathrm{}, \mathit{} and so on, to no avail.

Comment: @Sapiens You know what packages you’re loading.

Comment: Yes: 

[utf8]{inputenc}; [T1]{fontenc}; {color, xcolor, hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
 linkcolor={blue},
 citecolor={red}}

{soul, afterpage, epigraph}
[sfdefault]{ClearSans} 
{rotating}
[a4paper, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry} 
\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9} 

{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, mathtools}
{mathrsfs}

{scalerel}

{marvosym}
{eurosym}
{stmaryrd}

{cancel}

{bm}

{bbm}

{stackengine}
{graphicx}